# ggplot sf not rounding x-axis coordinate ticks properly

Tags: r, sf, ggplot

I have an issue plotting an sf object in ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N. It is not displaying the x-axis coordinate ticks well. Instead of 8.649° it is displaying 8.6490000000000000001°. Also see the image below for how it looks to me.

I am using sf_0.9-6, ggplot2_3.3.2 and R version 4.0.2 on Windows 10.

[image: Ugly x-axis]

Here's some sample code, so you can hopefully replicate it yourselves.

```
test <- structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(477799.11, 477832.22, 
                                          477832.22, 477799.11, 477799.11, 5632217.3, 5632217.3, 5632250.43, 
                                          5632250.43, 5632217.3), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
                                                                                                "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 477799.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                             ymin = 5632217.3, xmax = 477832.22, ymax = 5632250.43), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                               input = "ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 32N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",9,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - 6Â°E to 12Â°E and ETRS89 by country\"],\n        BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",25832]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = test)
```

I have tried to set xlim in `coord_sf()` to whole integer numbers however that did not change anything.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = test) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(477797, 477835),
           ylim = c(5632217, 5632250))
```

Does anyone of you know what might be wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are wrong, but you may want to get control on scales.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = test) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(8.6847, 8.6851, by = 0.0001)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(50.84125, 50.8415, by = 0.00005))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works. I might open an issue on github, I think that might be a better place for the underlying issue